# Issues with CSS hover and IE8

Tags: css

I am having issues with IE 8.
I have 2 table cells on a page where I don't want the 'hover' code below to work (they have text and are not links).
The cells are in the div transbox
I added the above 'stopcellhover' to accomplish this.
It works fine in all browsers (therefore no hover effect and opacity is maintained and the text is visible) except IE 8.
If I hover over the 2 cells in IE 8, I get the #666666 background color as a hover and the text is sometimes there, sometimes not.
I know there is a better way to do this, any help would be appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
td#nav {margin: 0 0 0 0;}
td.hover, td:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background:#1D1D34; }
td:hover > td { visibility: visible }
.stopcellhover:hover
{
background-color: #666666;
}
div.transbox
{
width:860px;
height:450px;
margin:50px 50px;
background-color:#666666;
opacity:.85;
filter:alpha(opacity=85);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85)";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=85);
-moz-opacity:.85; /* ff lt 1.5, netscape */
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

thanks
Paul

Comment: open up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see it in action

Answer (score 0):

Why are you applying the `:hover` to the `td` in the first place? I think you should apply it to the `a` only. Just display them as block to make them fill up the entire `td`.

This way you do not need to start overwriting your css code for special cases and adding classes to td's just to prevent them from showing the hover effect.

Also `:hover` is not well supported on non `a` tags (like the `td`) in legacy browsers. If you indeed set up a fiddle, I would be happy to demonstrate what i mean.